# How to increase console output at the android Log class

Tags: java, android, buffer, logging

For default Log on android platform has limited amount of character for console output. Around equal a bit more than 3000. Therefore, if the message is longer than 3000 characters, it is not shown on screen.

I have not found a better solution than this:

```
public class Log {
    private static int mode = android.util.Log.INFO;

    public static void e(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        if ((mode & android.util.Log.ERROR) <= 0) return;
        android.util.Log.e(tag, msg, tr);
    }

    public static void e(String tag, String msg) {
        if ((mode & android.util.Log.ERROR) <= 0) return;
        android.util.Log.e(tag, msg);
    }

    public static void w(String tag, String msg) {
        if ((mode & android.util.Log.WARN) <= 0) return;
        android.util.Log.w(tag, msg);
    }

    public static void i(String tag, String msg) {
        if ((mode & android.util.Log.INFO) <= 0) return;
        android.util.Log.i(tag, msg);
    }

    public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
        if ((mode & android.util.Log.DEBUG) <= 0) return;

            int length = msg.length();
            int kind = 3000;
            if (length >= kind) {
                int count = length / kind;
                int u = length % kind;
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                    int start = i * kind;
                    int end = start + kind;
                    android.util.Log.d(tag, msg.substring(start, end));
                }
                if (u != 0) {
                    int start = length - u;
                    int end = start + u;
                    android.util.Log.d(tag, msg.substring(start, end));
                }
            } else {
                android.util.Log.d(tag, msg);
            }
    }

}
```

Is there a better solution to this issue?

Comment: are you trying to wrap text of log outputs?

Comment: No, for default Log on android platform has limited amount of character  for console output. Around equal a bit more than 3000. Therefore, if the message is longer than 3000 characters, it is not shown on screen.

Comment: The kernel buffer for logcat holds 64KB of data.  There is a per-line limit of 1024 characters in the lower-level logging functions; after that the line is truncated.  I don't know where "3000" is coming from, or why something would disappear entirely.  Or why you're trying to log messages with more than 3K chars on one line.

Comment: it is necessary for example to print the JSON responses

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do, output GSON messages, but they're truncated making it difficult to debug.

Comment: IMHO console logging isn't the right approach to debug something like this. Either you need to step through the stuff with a debugger or you need to write all this junk to a file and then review it.

Comment: When I was working with android application with huge json response, I wanted to see this response  through adb logcat

Comment: Well, I've personally seen the per-line limit to be around 4000 characters (looking at one GSON output I see 3959) so I think the real answer must be device dependent. 1000 isn't large enough (every device I've tried is much closer to the 4k per-line size). The best answer I've seen for this has been to run the command: `adb logcat -g` and look at the max-payload size -- but even that's too big in my case (4068b) so I assume the payload includes more than just the message itself (ie: tag, date, etc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A workaround for the 1024 character limit when doing large outputs (JSON etc)
is to make a simple for-loop, logging them in chunks.

It may not be as elaborate as yours, but it's easy on the eyes and won't clutter the code too much.

```
        String json = data.toString();
        int length = json.length();

        for(int i=0; i<length; i+=1024)
        {
            if(i+1024<length)
                Log.d("JSON OUTPUT", json.substring(i, i+1024));
            else
                Log.d("JSON OUTPUT", json.substring(i, length));
        }
```