# Android not read all line from json file

Tags: android

I am trying to read content from local json file, but it not return all line in json file it just return some line only. Below is my code:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            final InputStream file = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tv);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append("\n");
                Log.d("String",line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("sdfsdf",text.toString());

        return text.toString();
    }
```

And result is :

```
{
        "items": [
          {
            "title": "TV5",
            "link": "http://mobile.interface.stmg.net.kh/nn_cms/nn_cms_view/jpz/n3_a_a.php?nns_version=2.3.7.0.2.SC-JPZ-IPAD.0.0_Release&nns_output_type=json&nns_user_agent=nn_pad/ipad/1.0.0&nns_language=en_US&nns_tag=28&nns_user_id=IPADB123456789089756745634523456CA&nns_device_id=&nns_buss_id=2000002&nns_category_id=1000001&nns_func=apply_play_video&nns_mac_id=112233445566&nns_media_assets_id=pad_live_v1&nns_media_id=c35345c8f040ffd74caddacff3d8b847&nns_video_id=3faaa5c9171d8529795749c88040b5ec&nns_video_index=0&nns_video_type=1",
            "thumbnail": "tv5.png",
            "direct" : false
          },
          {
            "title": "CTN",
            "link": "http://mobile.interface.stmg.net.kh/nn_cms/nn_cms_view/jpz/n3_a_a.php?nns_version=2.3.7.0.2.SC-JPZ-IPAD.0.0_Release&nns_output_type=json&nns_user_agent=nn_pad/ipad/1.0.0&nns_language=en_US&nns_tag=28&nns_user_id=IPADB123456789089756745634523456&nns_device_id=&nns_buss_id=2000002&nns_category_id=1000001&nns_func=apply_play_video&nns_mac_id=112233445566&nns_media_assets_id=pad_live_v1&nns_media_id=f4bb36746f145be94deb9c17d0965f74&nns_video_id=f942ece95cb181ee4111c9921737b575&nns_video_index=0&nns_video_type=1",
            "thumbnail": "ctn.png",
            "direct" : false
          },
          {
            "title": "MYTV",
            "link": "http://mobile.interface.stmg.net.kh/nn_cms/nn_cms_view/jpz/n3_a_a.php?nns_version=2.3.7.0.2.SC-JPZ-IPAD.0.0_Release&nns_output_type=json&nns_user_agent=nn_pad/ipad/1.0.0&nns_language=en_US&nns_tag=28&nns_user_id=IPADB123456789089756745634523456&nns_device_id=&nns_buss_id=2000002&nns_category_id=1000001&nns_func=apply_play_video&nns_mac_id=112233445566&nns_media_assets_id=pad_live_v1&nns_media_id=a89cdd8c6279eb0b584627e0f571a698&nns_video_id=00d0bfe34121cd8a998a4bf7fffd2c19&nns_video_index=0&nns_video_type=1",
            "thumbnail": "mytv.png",
            "direct" : false
          },
          {
            "title": "MSJTV",
            "link": "rtmp://124.248.165.18:1935/live/myStream",
            "thumbnail": "msj.png",
            "direct" : true
          },
          {
            "title": "ATV",
            "link": "rtmp://113.161.212.25/live2",
            "thumbnail": "atv.png",
            "direct" : true
          },
          {
            "title": "CNC",
            "link": "http://mobile.interface.stmg.net.kh/nn_cms/nn_cms_view/jpz/n3_a_a.php?nns_version=2.3.7.0.2.SC-JPZ-IPAD.0.0_Release&nns_output_type=json&nns_user_agent=nn_pad/ipad/1.0.0&nns_language=en_US&nns_tag=28&nns_user_id=IPADB123456789089756745634523456&nns_device_id=&nns_buss_id=2000002&nns_category_id=1000001&nns_func=apply_play_video&nns_mac_id=112233445566&nns_media_assets_id=pad_live_v1&nns_media_id=51cb3efed11a0094944cc78c7f950fdd&nns_video_id=305c725d29f8e7b9684e09e9d463669e&nns_video_index=0&nns_video_type=1",
            "thumbnail": "cnc.png",
            "direct" : false
          },
          {
            "title": "NTV",
            "link": "http://mobile.interface.stmg.net.kh/nn_cms/nn_cms_view/jpz/n3_a_a.php?nns_version=2.3.7.0.2.SC-JPZ-IPAD.0.0_Release&nns_output_type=json&nns_user_agent=nn_pad/ipad/1.0.0&nns_language=en_US&nns_tag=28&nns_user_id=IPADB123456789089756745634523456&nns_device_id=&nns_buss_id=2000002&nns_category_id=1000001&nns_func=apply_play_video&nns_mac_id=112233445566&nns_media_assets_id=pad_live_v1&nns_media_id=f1d34949aa405f5ff7bf9be51c9c48eb&nns_video_id=e72a42883ca4461c22b396c248cdb3c9&nns_video_index=0&nns_video_type=1",
            "thumbnail": "ntv.png",
            "direct" : false
          },
          {
            "title": "TV9",
            "link": "http://mobile.interface.stmg.net.kh/nn_cms/nn_cms_view/jpz/n3_a_a.php?nns_version=2.3.7.0.2.SC-JPZ-IPAD.0.0_Release&nns_output_type=json&nns_user_agent=nn_pad/ipad/1.0.0&nns_language=en_US&nns_tag=28&nns_user_id=IPADB123456789089756745634523456CA&nns_device_id=&nns_buss_id=2000002&nns_category_id=1000001&nns_func=apply_play_video&nns_mac_id=112233445566&nns_media_assets_id=pad_live_v1&nns_media_id=1745e6557435c9a424a1627642f39439&nns_video_id=07dbc29ba75ab5b8c5e2b300818ab6b9&nns_video_index=0&nns_video_type=1",
            "thumbnail": "tv9.png",
            "direct" : false
          },
          {
            "title": "TV3",
            "link": "http://mobile.in
```

Please help to suggest the best solution for me, Thanks,

Comment: Maybe your log console character limit exceeded.; Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668596/how-to-increase-console-output-at-the-android-log-class

Comment: Try to convert your string in json object using try catch block and check, if it is converted properly then it has read entire file otherwise not read full file, as it may be problem with logcat characters limit

Comment: Your code seems to be OK. How did you check that result? Do all the log messages show up?

Answer (score 0):

if the result is printed in logs this may be character limit for log.
use debugger to get value of Json and try to use some online tool to convert it into Json like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/